# Filtering out 'no solutions' after solving a high order polynomial

Tags: polynomials

I am dealing with a fourth order polynomial. I get all of the desired out put however above a certain range I also get these - {}. From my understanding this means that there is no solution. I am trying to plot the final output however {} runes any chance of that. How could I remove the 'no solution'?

I have tried Select and Reduce.

```
Ddd = (a1) Dd^4 - (a2) Dd + (a2);
Table[NSolve[Ddd == 0, Dd, Reals], {t, t3}];
```

My output looks like this:

```
{{1.*10^-7, 0.000312683}, {1.0056*10^-7, 5.29149*10^-7}, {1.01653*10^-7, 3.59975*10^-7}, {1.0323*10^-7,  2.83353*10^-7}, {1.05406*10^-7, 2.36121*10^-7}, {1.08473*10^-7, 2.02102*10^-7}, {1.13219*10^-7, 1.74367*10^-7}, {1.23859*10^-7,   1.45755*10^-7}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}}
```

I would just like to retain all the numbers an non of the rest.

Cheers for any ideas.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of ways:

```
sols = {{1.*10^-7, 0.000312683}, {1.0056*10^-7, 
    5.29149*10^-7}, {1.01653*10^-7, 3.59975*10^-7}, {1.0323*10^-7, 
    2.83353*10^-7}, {1.05406*10^-7, 2.36121*10^-7}, {1.08473*10^-7, 
    2.02102*10^-7}, {1.13219*10^-7, 1.74367*10^-7}, {1.23859*10^-7, 
    1.45755*10^-7}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, {}, \
{}};


DeleteCases[sols, {}]
sols /. {} -> Sequence[]
```

*Side remark:*

If your code is

```
sols = Table[NSolve[Ddd == 0, Dd, Reals], {t, t3}];
```

then the output should have the form

```
((sol11, sol12,...), {sol21,...}, ..., {}, {}, ...}
```

If so, you can get rid of the `{}` with

```
Flatten[sols, 1]
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael, that worked perfectly. I spent a really long time trying to find a way around it, I did not realize mathematica had this function...so much to learn.

Comment: @ValentinU You're welcome.